# Rank of mixed-unitary channel

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, quantum-information

Let $\mathcal{X}$ be a complex Euclidean space, let $n = \text{dim}(\mathcal{X})$,
and let $Φ ∈ C(\mathcal{X})$ be a mixed-unitary channel (it means that $\forall X,Φ(X)=\sum_{a}p_aU_aXU^{*}_a$). Prove that there exists a positive integer
$m$ satisfying $m ≤ n^4 − 2n^2+2$, a collection of unitary operators ${U_1, . . . , U_m} ⊂ U(\mathcal{X})$, a probability vector $(p_1, . . . , p_m)$ such that $Φ(X) =\sum_{k=1}^mp_kU_kXU^{*}_k$ for all $X$.

This problem is from Proposition 4.9 of [https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/~watrous/TQI/TQI.4.pdf](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/%7Ewatrous/TQI/TQI.4.pdf) and there is a proof in the link. But I don't understand what this means: "The Choi representation of $Ψ_U$ is therefore drawn from an affine subspace
of $Herm(\mathcal{X} ⊗ \mathcal{X} )$ having dimension $n^4 − 2n^2 + 1$". Also $\Xi$ defined there is not a bijection, what's the purpose of defining this map?

Also any ideas different from the proof in the link are welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Eq. (4.52) Watrous shows that for all $U\in\mathsf U(\mathcal X)$
$$
\Xi(J(\Psi_U))=\begin{pmatrix}{\bf 1}&0\\0&{\bf 1}\end{pmatrix}
$$
which is equivalent to
$
J(\Psi_U)-\tfrac1n{\bf 1}\otimes{\bf 1}\in\ker\Xi
$
as is readily verified.
Equivalently,
$$
\big\{J(\Psi_U):U\in\mathsf U(\mathcal X)\big\}\in\ker\Xi+\frac1n{\bf 1}\otimes{\bf 1}\subseteq\text{Herm}(\mathcal X\otimes\mathcal X)
$$
which together with Eq. (4.51) shows that the **Choi representation of $\Psi_U$** is drawn from $\{J(\Psi_U):U\in\mathsf U(\mathcal X)\}$ which is an **affine** ($+\frac1n{\bf 1}\otimes{\bf 1}$) subspace of $\text{Herm}(\mathcal X\otimes\mathcal X)$ of **dimension** $\dim(\ker\Xi)=(n^2-1)^2=n^4-2n^2+1$.

The reason Watrous introduces the map $\Xi$ in the first place is that once we know that the $J(\Psi_U)$ --- which by definition of mixed unitaries are the building blocks of all Choi representations $J(\Phi)$ we care about --- it suffices to know the dimension of the space these $J(\Psi_U)$ live in; the reason for this is [Carathéodory's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carath%C3%A9odory%27s_theorem_(convex_hull)) which turns the dimension of this subspace into an upper bound on the number of unitaries one needs.

Of course we could use the brute force argument that all $J(\Psi_U)$ live in $\text{Herm}(\mathcal X\otimes\mathcal X)$ so Carathéodory would yield $m\leq\dim(\text{Herm}(\mathcal X\otimes\mathcal X))+1=n^4+1$ where we [used that](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2840830) the Hermitian $n\times n$ matrices have (real) dimension $n^2$. With this in mind introducing $\Xi$ helped us to find a better upper bound for the space the unitary channels live in which in turns yielded a better upper bound for $m$.